# segregating data based on a picklist value

Tags: apex

```
List<CustomObject__c> listnew= [select Field1__c,Field2__c,  from CustomObject__c where Account__c =:currentRecordId ];

List<class name> list2 = new List<class name>();


  for (CustomObject__c CC: listnew) {
    for (Id intId: intMap.keySet()) {
        if (intId == custInt.Id) {
            list2.add(new OpportunityStatus(String.ValueOf(CC.Field1__c), String.ValueOf(CC.Field2__c)));
        }
    }
}
```

Here OpportunityStatus is a constructor. `Field2__c` is a picklist. Based on the 3 values, I want to segregate data.

Do I need to have 3 constructors (I guess no, since the parameters are going to be same)
Do I need to have 3 lists based on the value of picklist? [Currently I am adding to one list only]

Comment: can you explain in more detail what your end result would be like as I find your description quite confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a constructor can't be defined as a list. At first, I assumed you wanted to create a class to separate your data (Ids) into separate lists based on the whether their status matched `Field1__c`, `Field2__c` or neither since you don't provide a 3rd. Upon inspecting your code, it then became apparent that you wanted to add new status codes based on the values returned from your queries. It's not clear if you need to know those Ids or not. If you do, you'd want to return the data in map form.

I'm not entirely certain what CustomerJourney is in your org, but it's not a Standard Object. Here's a stab at what I think you're looking for based on what you've provided.

Also, there's no need to iterate on the `intMap.keySet().`You may also want to pass in a list of Ids rather than a single Id. However, you will need to pass the values of that keyset into this class, or if working from a visualforce page, grab it from an Apex properties getter.

Here's the class:

```
public with sharing class OppStatus{

set<id>intmapkeys;
public<Id,string>mapid2status = new map<Id,string>() {set;}
list<string>list2 {private set}
list<string>list3 {private set}

    public OppStatus(Id currentRecordId, set<Id> intmapkeys){
       List<CustomObject__c> listnew= [select Field1__c,Field2__c,  from CustomObject__c where Account__c =:currentRecordId ];
        getmapid2field(listnew,intmapkeys);
    }

    private static map<Id,string> getmapid2field(List<CustomObject__c> list new, set<id> intmapkeys){
       thisintmapkeys = (set<Id>)intmapkeys;     
       for (CustomObject__c CC: listnew) {
          if (intmapkeys.contains(cc.Id) {
             if(!isEmpty(cc.Field1__c)){
                 list2.add(new OpportunityStatus(String.ValueOf(CC.Field1__c)));
                 mapid2status.put(cc.Id,CC.Field1__c);
             }
             if(!isEmpty(cc.Field2__c)){
                 list2.add(new OpportunityStatus(String.ValueOf(CC.Field2__c)));
                 mapid2status.put(cc.Id,CC.Fiedl2__c);
             }
          else(
             list3.add(cc.Id)
             mapid2status.put(cc.Id,'same status');
          }
      }
      {
      set list2;
      set list3;
      // notice that i've set these two lists in case you want to send these to a vf page
      }
      return mapid2status;
    }
}
```

**Note:** this code was written "on the fly" and has not been tested or debugged. Consider it as a guide to use for writing your own code.